# Prometheus Increase function alert

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-alerts

So my goal is to set up alerting mechanism for network interface drops. I am using `node_network_receive_drop_total` which is a counter. My goal is to alert when drops occur meaning when count of drops go up. Lets say I have these values for drops over a period of time.

```
|node_network_receive_drop_total |difference
|0                               |0
|1                               |1
|5                               |4
|5                               |0  
|7                               |2
```

In this example, how can I use increase function and alert condition in grafana to alert when the difference is non-zero?

Answer (score 3):

In your example, you should use [delta function](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#delta). Something similar to:

```
delta(node_network_receive_drop_total[5m]) > 0
```

That means, whenever you have a delta greater than 0 in the last 5 minutes, your alert will be triggered.

**PS: consider using sum in case you have multiple instances.**

Comment: I dont think you can use delta with counters. Its only for use with Gauges

Answer (score 0):

In the `Query` tab a graph with a name something like `node network drops` and query something like this: `increase(node_network_receive_drop_total[5m])`.

When there are no drops, this graph should have a flat line at `0`. When there is a drop the graph will show a line at `1` for 5 mins after the drop.

In the Alert tab create an alert with condition of `WHEN max() OF query(A, 15m, now) IS ABOVE 0`.

As you will only have one value returned by the query you could use `max()`, `min()`, or `max()` (they will all return the same value).

The `A` in `query` should match the letter on your query in the `Query` tab. If you have more than one query displayed on the graph, you may need to change this.

`15m` and `now` look at data from the last 15m.

Comment: I did exactly this but I used sum by instances in the query. Thank you!:)